# Table relations disappearing

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012

I'm having a recurring problem in AX when trying to create custom tables with relations.  In short, the field definitions in the relations keep "disappearing".

I have 6 custom tables, with a total of 10 or so relations between them.  Every time I compile, I get at least one error saying "Relation incomplete due to missing fields".  I remove and re-add the relation, only to have it error out again later.

I have tried a database sync and an incremental CIL build.  Has anyone seen this before?  Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Well I am very pleased with your question!! That confirms I am truly not the only one in the world having this problem.

Let me tell you what I already tried.. (Please also check the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348641/xpo-import-relation-is-incomplete-due-to-missing-fields) I have posted that is related to it)

We are having the same issue within our build process. There, an XPO is imported into Ax and half of the tables is missing fields in relations. Importing the same XPO a second time solves most of the missing fields troubles, but does not fix all of the things going wrong with XPO imports.

I have already contacted some people I ran into from Microsoft and they are having a look at this one. Also, we logged an incident so that we also follow the official Microsoft flow for incident logging.

I will try and update this post here with the response I get from Microsoft.

Comment: I think this should probably be a comment, not an answer.

Anyway, I got a suggestion from a consultant to try the following, and it seems to have worked for now:

1) Restart AOS
2) Full CIL Compile
3) Restart AOS.

I also did a database sync somehwere in there.  The consultant thought this may have been a caching issue, so I would suggest you try these steps immediately before importing your XPO.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: This is performed in a clean standard environment. And today microsoft responded to the support request. Apparently they have been able to reproduce it by issueing the startup command. Now let's see if they find the cause to it.